# Error 500 al plublicar web blazor con cuentas individuales

Tags: iis, .net-core, blazor

Tengo el siguiente problema, seguro que es una tontería pero no doy.

Si creo un web con blazor web asembly sin cuentas de usuario, la compilo, la publico en un servidor IIS y funciona bien.

Si en cambio creo la misma aplicación blazor web asembly pero con cuentas de usuario inviduales, modifico el fichero setting para indicarle una base de datos sql server, compilo, ejecuto, registro un usuario y funciona bien, pero al publicarla y llevármela al IIS obtengo un error 500.

Lo he probado en dos servidores co el mismo resultado, por lo que creo que me falta alguna librería para el acceso a la base de datos (sin ella funciona bien)

Tengo instalado el módulo rewrite URL, las librerías net core 5 para hosting

Aclaro. No he tocado una sola línea de código de la aplicación que genera el Visual Studio. En el equipo de desarrollo donde tengo instalado el VS funciona, pero en el servidor no. Cuando ejecuto la página lo primero que obtengo es el ERROR 500. No hay log en el IIS ni nada.

Creo que el problema esta en la cadena de conexión. Yo quiero especificar un servidor con bases de datos con su usuario y contraseña, para ello, en el appsetting uso la cadena:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=SRV\\SQL;Database=blazor;Persist Security Info=True;User Id=sa;Password=1234;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
  },
```

En el Visor de Eventos del IIS obtengo:

```
Exception: 
System.ArgumentException: The 'ClientId' option must be provided. (Parameter 'ClientId')
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthOptions.Validate()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationOptions.Validate(String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`2.<AddSchemeHelper>b__1(TOptions o)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ValidateOptions`1.Validate(String name, TOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Get>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
```

Alguna idea

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Sería de gran utilidad para ti que añadieras en tu pregunta la traza de error completa. Resumir el error en Error 500 es limitar lo que los demás pueden ver y deja a todos adivinando cuál de las muchas cosas que puede salir mal, salió mal en tu caso. Enfócalo en encontrar la solución entre todos y no necesariamente en buscar a alguien que le pase lo mismo. Recuerda que puedes [edit] la pregunta para añadir detalles

Comment: @Alfabravo, Como indico en la modificación que he hecho de la pregunta, no es resumir a Error 500, es que solo tengo eso cuando accedo a la página, y a día de hoy no se hacer una traza a una página en "producción", si me dices como hacerlo, encantado.

Comment: Tengo exactamente el mismo problema, y no se como resolverlo, encontraron la forma de resolver esto??? ayuda!! please!!

Comment: Hola, Has creado un certificado para la aplicación? (no me refiero al certificado del dominio donde esta alojado la pagina)